# Recallibrating a based position from quaternion data

Tags: math, quaternions

I get a quaternion from my controller and set a model's rotation in my program based on that.
If I want to recalibrate a base point of the controller, I can capture the current sensor value as baseValue, and set the model to the base position with this:

```
modelRotation = sensorData * inverseOf(baseValue);
```

This works wonderfully, and the model is reset to the base position.

The problem is that if I rotate the controller on the Y axis and recalibrate, now rotation on the controller's x axis behaves as rotation on the model's z axis.

Is there a way to have the model always mimic the controller rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
modelRotation = inverseOf(baseValue) * sensorData;
```

Why?

I'm not sure why this is the solution to my problem, but I learned it was a possible solution on Math Stack Exchange: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228229/is-division-of-matrices-possible

I tried it, and it worked.